# Android Tools to browse sqlite file for debugging

Tags: android, sqlite

First of all, I have tried to get the SQLite file from DDMS in Eclipse. However, the data folder is empty.
Then, I researched on google and I found that this may be my device haven't root.
Is it true?
Does there any other methods that I can debug the SQlite file even if my device do not need to root?

Comment: The Best ever i have seen for Sqlite in android is here http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/working-with-sqlite-db-tutorial/ have a look that tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If You have the database file then you can Browse it.Their is **Plug-In** for **Morzilla Firefox** called **[SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/?src=search)**.Now you can Export the sqlite file..i mean **database file** from **eclipse DDMS** to your PC and import that file in the **SQLite Manager**..their you can see all your *tables and Data* for *Debugging* purpose.This was the way i used.

Comment: Thx. The question is I can't get the file now

Comment: /data should not be empty in Normal states...as it should contains the project folder,and the project in turn should contain the database folder which would host all the database files used in the project.I hope so their might be some problem with your Emulator creation..Can you please try to create a new Emulator itself,and then run your project in that emulator,and then again check the data folder..please please try this once...i really want your reply....Regards.

Comment: I have run the project to my second device. /data is full of folder

Comment: Ok then Now try to locate your Project folder....the names would start like com.....yourprojectname

Comment: Exploring that..you would see the database folder...in that you would see your table name...export that to you PC..and as said above..get SQLite manager from the above link and then you can see your table values

Comment: I can do it with my second device. The problem is I want to get the db from my first(unrooted) device.

Comment: Why...have you removed the data that was in the first Device??

Comment: Then try this..normally close the Emulator..now again try to open it from Eclipse...then you may be able to see this folder in this restarted Emulator..